# I am looking for the best way to parsing html code

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

Im working on an application to school. Its task is to read the subject name and div class name. Class name is different than if you were present or not.
At the end I have to summarize the attendance rate for each individual school subject for the whole year.

The code is from one day. I have to do it for every day of the year. Then summarize it to percentages.

I tried to use BeautyfulSoup but it's a very tedious job.

#### For example:

**'przedmiot obecnosc_3'** - *student was not present in class*

**'przedmiot obecnosc_0'** - *student was present in class*

**'2 jęz. obcy/jęz. niemiecki'** - *name of school subject*

```
<td id="dzien_30" class="dzienMiesiaca" style="height: 144px;">
    <div class="dzienMiesiacaHead">30</div>
    <div class="okienko">-</div>
    <div id="przedmiot_142" class="przedmiot obecnosc_3" </div> ### needed name of class ###
        <div class="cOznacz"></div>
        2 - 2 jęz. obcy/jęz. niemiecki #### subject name ###
    </div>
    <div id="przedmiot_143" class="przedmiot obecnosc_0" onclick="PokazInfoPrzedmiot(143);">
        <div class="cOznacz"></div>
        3 - matematyka rozszerzona
    </div>
    <div id="przedmiot_144" class="przedmiot obecnosc_0" onclick="PokazInfoPrzedmiot(144);">
        <div class="cOznacz"></div>
        4 - matematyka rozszerzona
    </div>
    <div id="przedmiot_145" class="przedmiot obecnosc_0" onclick="PokazInfoPrzedmiot(145);">
        <div class="cOznacz"></div>
        5 - wychowanie fizyczne
    </div>
    <div id="przedmiot_146" class="przedmiot obecnosc_0" onclick="PokazInfoPrzedmiot(146);">
        <div class="cOznacz"></div>
        6 - wychowanie fizyczne
    </div>
    <div id="przedmiot_147" class="przedmiot obecnosc_0" onclick="PokazInfoPrzedmiot(147);">
        <div class="cOznacz"></div>
        7 - 1 jęz. obcy/jęz. angielski
    </div>
    <div id="przedmiot_148" class="przedmiot obecnosc_0" onclick="PokazInfoPrzedmiot(148);">
        <div class="cOznacz"></div>
        8 - informatyka rozszerzona
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Beautiful Soup is generally the best way to do parse HTML in Python.

Comment: Well, `BeautifulSoup` is normally the go-to library when it comes to analyzing HTML in a programmer-friendly way. I mean, you could try `lxml` or `html.parser`, but that would probably be way more tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `html_data` is the code snippet from your question, you could do something like this:

This will create `subjects` dictionary, where key is subject name and values are lists with two values - first value is number of hours when student was present and second value is number of hours when student was absent:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')

subjects = {}
for subject in soup.select('[class*="obecnosc_"]'):
    not_present = 'obecnosc_3' in subject.attrs['class']
    subjects.setdefault(subject.get_text(strip=True), [0, 0])[not_present] += 1

from pprint import pprint
pprint(subjects)
```

Prints:

```
{'2 - 2 jęz. obcy/jęz. niemiecki': [0, 1],
 '3 - matematyka rozszerzona': [1, 0],
 '4 - matematyka rozszerzona': [1, 0],
 '5 - wychowanie fizyczne': [1, 0],
 '6 - wychowanie fizyczne': [1, 0],
 '7 - 1 jęz. obcy/jęz. angielski': [1, 0],
 '8 - informatyka rozszerzona': [1, 0]}
```

Comment: It's works! I owe you a beer!